# Mortar starting to chip - again

Tags: brick

11 months ago I had chipping brick mortar on the platform to the front door.

I followed this "Old House" video

[This Old House](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vk-0EPvWejI)

It looked like this when I finished...

[image: Before]

Now, it has begun to chip again (and this entrance is used only 5% of the year)...

[image: after]

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you summarise the steps from the video, so we can read it in 10 seconds rather than have to spend 10 minutes trying to extract the salient points? [This also prevents link-rot from removing all relevant info from the question].

Comment: Are you referring to 're-pointing' the brickwork, which involves replacing the mortar in the joints between the bricks, or are you referring making repairs to that cement/concrete-looking section in front of the bricks?

Comment: Your problem appears to be you are using a very thin coat of mortar on an uneven but smooth surface (nothing to hang on to) this combined to a dark colored surface that expands will pop the thin stuff out. Remove the grout line and use a acrylic latex expansion joint seal there after roughing up and repairing also use some add mix to the mortar the addmix helps bonding and with a expansion joint seal there it should not pop off after a few warm days.

Comment: @Tetsujin 1) used a masonry blade on circular saw to remove 1/4" of old mortar 2) cleaned and let dry 3) applied mortar and used pointing tool to smooth.  ... in a nutshell

Comment: @brhans Yes, 're-pointing' the brickwork

Comment: @Ed Beal  Let me read that back to you:  I remove the brick-to-slab mortar, rough the joint, apply acrylic latex expansion joint seal (instead of mortar) to the brick-to-slab joint.  This is due to the dark red brick expanding at a different rate than the slab.  Correct?

Comment: What type mortar did you use? if you used type S, it is great for exterior extremes, but very brittle. You may need to use a softer mortar like type N or O, if not type I I would also cut the grooves deeper, at least 3/4", dampen, not wet the brick, and after the mortar is set keep it damp for a few days.

Comment: I believe your problem will continue with thermal cycles and the thin layer of mortar, by using a flexible joint the slab may not chip out as bad but it is thin soot may continue

Comment: You may also have a "deeper" issue. I see hair line cracks along the edges and corners of the brick that may suggest there is movement there. No amount of repointing will stabilize that.

Comment: @Jack  Yes, I do have some hairline cracks (in brick-to-brick joints).  Those bricks are set in a bed of (what appears to be) fine sand.  I had to dig out three bricks in the upper right of the photo, reset those and mortar deep.

Comment: _You_ may only use these pavers 1 day out of 20 (5%), but the weather uses them 24/7/365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the pavers are set on a sand base and can shift in one manner or another, or if in freezing weather, and the sand gets wet enough, ice may heave the brick to make anything you do crack.

Most times when pavers are set on a sand base, a sand and cement dust is swept in the joints, but the brick are laid tight with no joints to speak of. There are special mixes of sand and cement that are available in supply houses that have a polymer added to it to add flexibility to the joints.

This may not answer the actual question, but it will a possible remedy, if you wish to get past the cracks and failing mortar. Not mentioned until now, to use the sand mix, it would mean removing all the joint material, at least, I think it would require it. If you want to stick with mortar, it would still mean removing the brick, setting them in a masonry cement base instead of sand, then fill the joints with what you choose.